# Add title to a field name in the page layout

Tags: page-layout, aspx

How do I display in the page next to the information entered.  Code below.  I have a DateTime field that displays the DateTime as entered by the user.  How can I give it a title??

For Example

End Date : 01/01/2013

```
<div>


            <PageFieldDateTimeField:DateTimeField FieldName="8a121252-85a9-443d-8217-a1b57020fadf" runat="server">

            </PageFieldDateTimeField:DateTimeField>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FieldProperty control. See http://blog.mastykarz.nl/showing-names-site-columns-page-layout/ for more information and a code example.